# JavaScript code executing after return

Tags: javascript

In the following example, JavaScript seems to be completely ignoring my `return` statement, and just carrying on executing code.

```
var x = 1;
(function() {
  x = 2;
  return;
  var x = 3;
})();
console.log(x); // Outputs 1 in both Chrome and FF
```

Surely the code should output `2`? If I remove the `var` keyword from `var x = 3`, it outputs `2` as expected. Is there some strange compiler optimization at work here?

Comment: I think the `x` is different inside the function.. easy fix would be to do `window.x = 2`

Comment: As @dystroy said variable declarations get hoisted to the top of the function scope. So because you have the var x = 3, var x get's hoisted to the top and makes the x = 2 a local variable. If you just put x = 3 (without var) then the console.log will output 2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the code shouldn't output 2 because variable declarations are hoisted so your code is equivalent to

```
var x = 1;
(function() {
  var x;
  x = 2; // changes the internal x variable
  return;
  x = 3; // does nothing because it's not reached
})();
console.log(x); // Outputs the outside x, which is still 1
```

The line

```
x = 2;
```

only changes the internal `x` variable which shadows the outside one.

The scope of a non global variable is the **entire** function in which it is declared. From the start of this function to its end.